# Javascript interpreter only being executed on the first page

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I have the following class to return me the HTML of any given WebPage:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl, SIGNAL
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.dammit import UnicodeDammit
import sys
import signal


class Render(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.html = None
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
        self.connect(self, SIGNAL('loadFinished(bool)'), self._finished_loading)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _finished_loading(self, result):
        self.html = self.mainFrame().toHtml()
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(UnicodeDammit(self.html).unicode_markup)
        self.app.quit()
```

And I have a loop to iterate over list of WebPages with JavaScript that need to be run, such as:

```
l = ["http://host.com/page1", "http://host.com/page2"]

for page in l:
    soup = Render(page).soup
    #Do-something
```

Problem is that the JavaScript code is only executed in the first page that's loaded, not interpreting any after that.

Comment: That's probably because `QWebPage` doesn't wait for javascript execution before emitting the `loadFinished` signal

Comment: Shouldn't the first run also fail to execute it then?

Comment: Not necessarily, it probably loads fast enough on your first page, or perhaps the javascript isn't completely rendered

Comment: @X.Jacobs I don't think `loadFinished` is the reason. Since qt documentation states: The `loadStarted()` signal is emitted when the view begins loading. The `loadProgress()` signal, on the other hand, is emitted whenever an element of the web view completes loading, such as an embedded image, a **script**, etc. Finally, the `loadFinished()` signal is emitted when the view has loaded completely.

Comment: @nymk Yes, the script may be loaded, but not rendered

Comment: @user2055077, I have a question based on your code. I'm using your Render class, it works fine at the first time, but always when call it for a second time, it gives me this error:  `QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::configurationAdded `

Answer (score 0):

It probably the page has been loaded successfully, but it has more than one frame. To be more precise, sometimes `page.mainFrame().childFrames()` is not empty. You need to process not only the main frame, but also its children.
For example:

```
def _finished_loading(self, result):
    self.html = self.mainFrame().toHtml()
    self.soup = BeautifulSoup(UnicodeDammit(self.html).unicode_markup)
    # process childFrames
    self.htmls = [frame.toHtml() for frame in self.mainFrame().childFrames()]
    self.soups = [BeautifulSoup(UnicodeDammit(html).unicode_markup) for html in self.htmls]
    self.app.quit()
```